# The simplest way of getting Samba server

Tags: samba, storage, nas

Im looking for distro or a way to install samba server or nas for my other machines (mixed breed, various windows and linuxes) as simple as possible. If it takes changing/creating system files by hand it is no go. If it cant be done as simple as direct install from burned iso or by some wizzard program, tell me anyway.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install Samba?

Comment: Didnt try yet. Trying to find the best way so i can just install and go. Sugest me some.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ifyou are not bound to ubuntu or linux in common, try using BSD based NAS systems ([FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) or [NAS4Free](http://www.nas4free.org/). If you want linux based, try [OpenMediaVault](http://www.openmediavault.org/)

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest way since you are asking for Ubuntu** support is to install Samba (as well as many thousands of apps) using Ubuntu's commandline **apt** tool.  Install from the default repository.

To get to the commandline interface, hit this keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Then at the run this at the terminal prompt:

```
$ sudo apt install samba
```

Edit the`/etc/samba/smb.conf` file to create the shares you want to provide on the server.

Create the directory you want to share (or use a directory you already have) then add the share to the `smb.conf` file.

**Creating a shared folder:**

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt2/mysharedfolder
```

**Add the share to the server:**

Sample share entry (/etc/samba/conf):

```
[sharedfolder]
        comment = My Server Shared Folder
        path = /mnt2/mysharedfolder
        force user = user1
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        create mask = 0700
        valid users = user1, user2
```

Change `user#` for real user names that you have created on your server and created a samba account.

Create the samba account with:

```
$ sudo smbpasswd -a user1
```

Other available configurations such as **mask** are explained in details in the notes of the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.  You can also access the manual using the commands `man samba` or `man smb.conf`.

After making a change to the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` be sure to restart the samba server with:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart smbd
```

You might consider upgrading your Ubuntu OS to the lastest `LTS` version, which currently is version `16.04`, which will be supported with release updates for the next 5 years.  A non lts version will have release updates for less than a year.