# How to correctly partiton this server?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, multiple-users

I am setting up my first home media server and am struggling to identify if I have this correct.

I have two hard drives: one SSD at 250GB, one HDD at 1TB. I also need to have two unique users and a root user.
Ideally I would like the SSD to contain the server OS and be where any applications are installed. And the HDD to contain the home directories of the users, and all the media and documents of the users.

I believe it should go like:

- dev/sda1 = swap
- dev/sda2 = /
- dev/sdb1 = /home/server_name

I'm struggling though because I have two user accounts made and they are listed in parallel to /home and I can't figure out if they are actually mounted on /home or on /.

I don't have a problem doing a clean install if that is easiest, I just want to get this right so I don't have to re-do this.

Comment: You haven't given any release details (later releases can use swap files so the separate swap partition isn't necessary), and your /home-server_name isn't an issue, but are you meaning server_name is one of your two users?  (directories on /home are normally reserved for user directories, not shared directories). If you created a separate /home partition, user directories will be stored there, if there isn't one then user directories are forced to be saved on / partition.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry for the lack of info. On Ubuntu Server 20.04. Each user does have their own home directory, but I mounted the HDD in /home during installation. This is what fstab shows: "/home/server_name was on /dev/sdb1 during curtin installation"

Comment: @user535733 If I were to do that route, whats the best way to mount the HDD to /media/shared and use that within a Samba share?

Comment: @AaronW0820 that's a completely different question that you didn't raise above. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/886335/the-simplest-way-of-getting-samba-server for how somebody else did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu will happily work with a swap**file** instead of a separate partition.

Opinion: Without a separate swap partition:

- SSD EFI partition (created by the installer)
- SSD single partition for root (/) and /home and everything else except media
- HDD Media single partition, mounted at /media/shared or /var/media

Answer (score 0):

The users will be mounted in /home/username. If you want to set up a separate partition for each user then you may create two partitions and use fstab to mount that in /home/username folder.